# Array.reduce strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, arrays, types, reduce

**Hello everyone !**

I'm currently working to get a user input and parse it my way. The input represents integer ranges or single integers.
Let's say I get the following ranges array :

```
const ranges = [`1-6`, `8`, `12-20-18`, `22-21`, `46-42-44`];
```

Now I need a complete integer list so I wrote this chunk :

```
const list = ranges.reduce ((array, range) => {
    console.log (array);
    if (!range.incldues (`-`)) return array.push (parseInt (range)); // Single integer
    const milestones = range.split (`-`).map (milestone => parseInt (milestone)),
        min = Math.min (...milestones),
        max = Math.max (...milestones);
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) array.push (i);
    console.log (array);
    return array;
}, []);
```

The thing is I quicly got a "Uncaught TypeError: array.push is not a function" and console.logging my variables showed that after the first reduce iteration, array took the value (int) 7, despite being an array just before the return statement.

[Here is an illustration of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KMkf.png)

Could someone point out where it went wrong ? How to prevent it doing so ? And furthermore, if someone could explain WHY it went wrong, it would be perfect.

Thanks !

Comment: you don't need the special case `if (!range.incldues (`-`))` the code would work without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

- The method name is `.includes` (not `incldues`)
- `Array.prototype.push` returns the *new length* of the array, not the array itself. Use `push` first, then use `return array` on the next line.

Fix those, and it works as expected:

```js
const ranges = [`1-6`, `8`, `12-20-18`, `22-21`, `46-42-44`];
const list = ranges.reduce((array, range) => {
  if (!range.includes(`-`)) {
    array.push(parseInt(range)); // Single integer
    return array;
  }
  const milestones = range.split(`-`).map(Number),
    min = Math.min(...milestones),
    max = Math.max(...milestones);
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) array.push(i);
  return array;
}, []);
console.log(list);
```

Note that because the `Number` function converts a non-number to a number, you can simply pass it to `.map` rather than using `.map (milestone => parseInt (milestone))` (which is a bit wordy).

Comment: Ok, thanks ! (includes was a typo I made creating this question, wasn't in the code). I didn't know it just returned the array length and indeed, it works properly now. Was really a newb question :(
Thanks again ;)